# Amazon Glacier - Get list of archives in a vault

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-glacier

We have a 3rd party amazon-glacier vault which we want to access and download data form there. Is there a way via the JAVA SDK/3rd party library to get the list of archiveIDs that are present in a vault ? As I far I played around with the sdk, the describeVault() returns only the number of archives in the vault, and not the list itself.
If I get the list of archiveIDs I can create/initiate jobs for all the archives as per my use case. The boto python library does have this functionality, is there a way to do this in JAVA ?

Comment: are you referring to `listParts` from the boot lib ? then the equivalent method exist in java sdk in the `AmazonGlacierClient` class

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is possible in Java, as is in all AWS SDKs.

There are two steps to retrieve a list of archives that are present in a vault:

1. Call `AmazonGlacierClient.initiateJob` ([docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/glacier/AmazonGlacierClient.html#initiateJob(com.amazonaws.services.glacier.model.InitiateJobRequest))) to request an inventory retrieval, with `type` in `JobParameters` set to `inventory-retrieval`

Wait a couple of hours for the job to complete, and then

2. Call `AmazonGlacierClient.getJobOutput` ([docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/glacier/AmazonGlacierClient.html#getJobOutput(com.amazonaws.services.glacier.model.GetJobOutputRequest))) to retrieve the inventory, which contains the list of archives and their corresponding archiveIDs in one vault.